# Wave equation and Cauchy problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Consider the 1-D linear wave equation $u_{tt}=c^2 u_{xx} (c>0)$ on R.Suppose we are given $u(x,0)=\phi (x)$, $u_t(x,0)=\psi(x)$ ,where $\phi$ and $\psi$ are two given smooth functions. Use the form of the general solution to determine the solution of the Cauchy problem.

I know the general solution is given $u(x,t)=f(x-ct)+g(x+ct)$, but I am not sure how to proceed. A hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_formula, or any standard book on partial differential equations.